# Easy method of writing a sum of a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help finding a simple method of writing a simple equation for power series/ maclaurin series. Do I look at how the series develops or could I write the equation based on the sigma notation itself.

an example of this is:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(n+1)!}
$$
How do I write a simple equation for this series?

Comment: Starting point: think of the basic power series you know. What looks similar? Can you manipulate it?

Comment: Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{(n+1)!}$ not simple, or from what equation do you talk? take 1/(n+1) outside the sum  and you have $e^{x^2}$

Answer (score 1):

The equation for that series is:

$$
\frac{-1 + e^{x^2}}{x^2}
$$

To find this, you start with the basic series with a function you already know. For example the geometric series:
$$\frac{1}{1 - x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots,$$
And then through algebra and working through the series editing you will work through the math to turn
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \rightarrow  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(n+1)!} $$

For example the first step you can take is make $n$ into $2n$ :

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} =   \frac{1}{1 - x^2}
$$

(also another hint, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$)

Comment: thank you so much this way more insightful than the solution sheet for my test exam

Comment: i did what you told me to do and ended up with: ∑∞n=0 x^2n/n!=e/(1-x^2). how do i increase the factorial from n! to n+1!

Comment: You should be a bit careful, since the series $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$. If you are trying to solve the problem, it's best you play around with that series.